# Hidden some image in gridview

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp

I have a gridview with 3 images. I want when in offline mode, then 2 images (media and paket) are not displayed.

XAML:

```
    <GridView
                    x:Name="contentGrid"
                    Margin="60,15,5,10"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Image
                            x:Name="mediaImage"
                            Width="220"
                            Height="220"
                            Source="/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-mediaguru-notext.png" />

                         <Image
                                x:Name="paketImage"
                                Width="220"
                                Height="220"
                                Source="/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-paketabc-black.png" />

                        <Image
                            x:Name="umumImage"
                            Width="220"
                            Height="220"
                            Source="/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-buku-umum.png" />
</Gridview>
```

Code:

```
if(((App)(App.Current)).Mode == "Offline")
            {
                mediaImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                paketImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                mediaImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                paketImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
```

I am having a problem, which looks like the image below:
[image]

I want the third image to slide left and not perforated like that. How to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `GridView`, each item is a `GridViewItem`. Image can be hidden, but `GridViewItem` as an item still exists. They will occupy their place.

For your situation, I suggest that you use a data set with a `GridView` to generate items. When needed, you can control the items displayed by the `GridView` by modifying the data set.

```cs
private const string MediaImageUrl = "/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-mediaguru-notext.png";
private const string PaketImageUrl = "/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-paketabc-black.png";
private const string UmumImageUrl = "/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-buku-umum.png";

private ObservableCollection<string> ImageCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ImageCollection.Add(UmumImageUrl);
    if (((App)(App.Current)).Mode != "Offline")
    {
        ImageCollection.Insert(0, MediaImageUrl);
        ImageCollection.Insert(1, PaketImageUrl);
    }
}
```

```xml
<GridView ...
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ImageCollection}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <Image Width="220"
                   Height="220"
                   Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

If you need to remove the picture in the future, you can directly operate on the collection:

```cs
ImageCollection.Remove(MediaImageUrl);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, sorry if I didn't.

I would suggest the following changes.

1. Instead of Height/Width use MaxHeight/MaxWidth, you could also stick with Height=220, but the Width must be changed to MaxWidth
2. Use HorizontalAlignment = Left, for the image you want to position Left, and make GridView HorizontalAlignment Stretch

---

```
<GridView
    x:Name="contentGrid"
    Margin="60,15,5,10"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image
            x:Name="mediaImage"
            MaxWidth="220"
            MaxHeight="220"
            Source="/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-mediaguru-notext.png" />
         <Image
                x:Name="paketImage"
                MaxWidth="220"
                MaxHeight="220"
                Source="/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-paketabc-black.png" />
        <Image
            x:Name="umumImage"
            MaxWidth="220"
            MaxHeight="220"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Source="/images/revisi/new/menu/KS4-level-2-buku-umum.png" />
</Gridview>
```